# Matrix Square Root Singularity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-decomposition, indeterminate-forms

I have a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\nabla f = [f_x, f_y]$
 and a matrix 
$$
M = 
(1 + f_x^2 + f_y^2)^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 + f_y^2 & -f_xf_y & 0 \\
-f_xf_y   & 1 + f_x^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \xi^{-1}(1 + f_x^2 + f_y^2)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\xi >0$. Note it is symmetric positive definite.

I want the matrix square root of $M$. 
However, I found:
$$
\sqrt{M} = (f_x^2 + f_y^2)^{-1} 
\begin{bmatrix}
f_y^2 +f_x^2Q & f_xf_y(Q-1) & 0\\
f_xf_y(Q-1)   & f_x^2 + f_y^2Q &0 \\
0 & 0 & (f_x^2 + f_y^2)\xi^{-1/2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $ Q=\sqrt{(1 + f_y^2 + f_x^2)^{-1}} $.

This does indeed satisfy $\sqrt{M}\sqrt{M}=M$
but has a serious problem: $\sqrt{M}$ is inderminate when $f_x, f_y\equiv 0$. I expected $\sqrt{M}=I$ in such a case (assuming $\xi=1$).

**How can I fix $\sqrt{M}$ to not blow up when $\nabla f$ vanishes?**